# How to reduce memory:

Tags: java, memory

I need to create the input graph(graph with backward edges). Ex: 1-st graph has edges from 1 to 2, from 2 to 3; input graph has edges from 3 to 2, from 2 to 1.
The problem is that I'm creating matrix (N^N memory usage). How to use less memory for this task?

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ReverseGraph{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        int n = Integer.parseInt(scan.nextLine()); // number of vertices
        //matrix of vertices
        int[][] matrix = new int[n][n];
        Scanner sc;
//create graph by input method(if A vertex associates with B vert than put "1" on B row, A column)
        for(int i = 0; i < n;i++){
            String line = scan.nextLine();
            sc = new Scanner(line);
            while(sc.hasNextInt()){
                matrix[sc.nextInt() - 1][i] = 1;
            }

        }
        scan.close();

//Begin write the input graph       
        System.out.println(n); //write num of vertices

        //write
        for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
            for(int j = 0; j < n; j++){
                if(matrix[i][j] == 1)
                    System.out.print((j+1) + " ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: A matrix is only one of many data structures that might be used to store the graph. While it's CPU performance is very good, it's space performance is quite bad. What other data structures have you looked at?

Comment: @BobDalgleish I have already looked "adjacency list". However, to my mind, adj list uses not much less memory than matrix.

Comment: @VladokAC - maybe you should rethink that.  A matrix will take O(N^2) space where N is the number of nodes.  An adjacency list will take O(L) space where L is the number of links.

Comment: @StephenC Hmm, really!) And, how can I write links? by using the Bag<Integer>[]? Or is there another way?

Comment: A link can be as simple as a array of two integers, or a class with two integer fields.  (There is no `Bag` class ...).  Also consider `Map<Integer,<Set<Integer>>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Options for reducing the memory footprint.

- An adjacency list implemented as an `ArrayList<int[]>` where the `int[]` are 2-element arrays each of which represents a link.
- As above, except using a custom class with two `int` fields to represent a link.
- As a `HashMap<Integer, HashSet<Integer>>` or `HashMap<Integer, HashSet<Integer>>` or `HashMap<Integer, TreeSet<Integer>>`, where each set or list represents the destinations of the links.
- The equivalent to the above using [Trove collection types](http://trove4j.sourceforge.net/javadocs/).

All of these<sup>1</sup> are `O(L)` on the number of links rather `O(N^2)` on the number if nodes.

---

<sup>1 - Apart from the variations that use `TreeSet` ...</sup>